# postman: how to create a Pre-request Script to set an environment var with a random element in an array

Tags: arrays, random, postman

I need to create in postman a Pre-request script to set an environment variable with a random element in an array of values. 
anybody has an idea?

Edited: (solved)

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var order_id = ["one","two","three","four","five"];



function getRandomInt(min, max) { 

min = Math.ceil(min); 
max = Math.floor(max); 

return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
} 
pm.environment.set("order_id", order_id[getRandomInt(0,4)]);
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Also, please note that SO is **not a Code Writing** site. Please provide a minimal code/ instance of what u have tried.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-js -->var order_id = ["one","two","three","four","five"];
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

pm.environment.set("order_id", order_id[getRandomInt(0,4)]);

Comment: solved for my test

Answer (score 0):

Postman has many built-in modules that allow you to do things like this without the need to write native JS code in that way.

Remove the function and just add this, it will do the same thing using the [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) `random()` function:

```
const order_id = ["one","two","three","four","five"]

pm.environment.set("order_id", order_id[_.random(0,4)])
```

Or just use the Lodash `shuffle` function:

```
const order_id = ["one","two","three","four","five"]

pm.environment.set("order_id", _.shuffle(order_id)[0])
```